# Setting iframe height to scrollHeight in ReactJS

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs, iframe, reactive-programming

- The typical solution to the problem doesn't work in in React due to
  its dynamically generated component structure and event model, as opposed to
  traditional static HTML:

script:

```
<script>
  function resizeIframe(obj) {
    obj.style.height = obj.contentWindow.document.body.scrollHeight + 'px';
  }
</script>
```

html:

```
<iframe src="..." frameborder="0" scrolling="no" onload="resizeIframe(this)" />
```

- There is a npm package `react-iframe`, but it looks unfinished
  (accepts only props `url`, `width`, `height`):

  https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-iframe
- The likely part of the solution is to listen to the `load` event of
  the `iframe`, but in a way that is compatible with React.

Is there a way in React to set the height of an `iframe` to the height of its scrollable contents?

my code:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react'
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom'
import Iframe from 'react-iframe'

export default class FullheightIframe extends Component {

    componentDidMount() {
        console.log("IFRAME DID MOUNT");
    }

    renderReactFrame() {
        return (
            <Iframe url="http://www.example.com" width="100%" height="100%" onLoad={()=>{console.log("IFRAME ON LOAD")}}></Iframe>
        );
    }

    renderHTMLFrame() {
        return (
            <iframe 
                onLoad={(loadEvent)=>{
                    // NOT WORKING var frameBody = ReactDOM.findDOMNode(this).contentDocument.body; // contentDocument undefined
                    // NOT WORKING obj.nativeEvent.contentWindow.document.body.scrollHeight // contentWindow undefined
                }} 
                ref="iframe" 
                src="http://www.example.com" 
                width="100%" 
                height="100%" 
                scrolling="no" 
                frameBorder="0"
            />
        );
    }

    render() {
        return (
            <div style={{maxWidth:640, width:'100%', height:'100%', overflow:'auto'}}>
                {this.renderHTMLFrame()}
            </div>
        );
    }
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

What you want to do is in your componentDidMount, run the script to set the height. [If you are loading external content, you might want to add event listener on the IFrame to wait until the external content is loaded.]

```
   componentDidMount() {
       const obj = ReactDOM.findDOMNode(this);
       obj.style.height = obj.contentWindow.document.body.scrollHeight + 'px';
    }
```

There is another, more "reacty" way of doing this - where you would store the height in state.

```
   componentDidMount() {
       const obj = ReactDOM.findDOMNode(this);
       this.setState({iFrameHeight:  obj.contentWindow.document.body.scrollHeight + 'px'});
    }
```

and then in your render:

```
render() {
    return (
        <div style={{maxWidth:640, width:'100%', height:this.state.iFrameHeight, overflow:'auto'}}>
            {this.renderHTMLFrame()}
        </div>
    );
}
```

Comment: This solution should work, but it doesn't (not finding `obj`): `Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'document' of undefined`

Comment: Update: This was fixed by using the `iframe` as root element in the component's return method. Now the problem is that height is being set to `8px`. Probably because the iframe is yet not being fully loaded.

Comment: Cannot read property 'document' of undefined - that means contentWindow is not found - that means iFrame is not loaded. That means you need to add event listener to iFrame - iframe.addEventListener('load', function() { ...

Answer (score 12):

Here is the answer, but first two important things.

- Iframe has to be the root component in the `render()` method
- The height has to be captured from the `onLoad` event (once the iframe if fully loaded)

Here is the full code:

```
import React, { Component, PropTypes } from 'react'
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom'

export default class FullheightIframe extends Component {

    constructor() {
        super();
        this.state = {
            iFrameHeight: '0px'
        }
    }

    render() {
        return (
            <iframe 
                style={{maxWidth:640, width:'100%', height:this.state.iFrameHeight, overflow:'visible'}}
                onLoad={() => {
                    const obj = ReactDOM.findDOMNode(this);
                    this.setState({
                        "iFrameHeight":  obj.contentWindow.document.body.scrollHeight + 'px'
                    });
                }} 
                ref="iframe" 
                src="http://www.example.com" 
                width="100%" 
                height={this.state.iFrameHeight} 
                scrolling="no" 
                frameBorder="0"
            />
        );
    }
}
```

Comment: This doesnt work in cross origin. Anyone know how to do it in cross origin?

Comment: @cabaji99 most iframe related resizing tools aren't going to work cross-origin. for cross-origin, the third party page has to have code added to it that authorizes and handles communication to the parent page.

Comment: @cabaji99 Take a look at https://www.npmjs.com/package/iframe-resizer-react for cross origin iframe resizing

Comment: @DavidBradshaw Thank you!

Answer (score 8):

A couple of things to note here:

- You can use refs to get a reference to the iframe instead of having to search for it
- Use the onLoad() handler from the iframe to ensure that the content has loaded before you try to resize it - if you try to use React's lifecycle methods like `componentDidMount()` you run the risk of the content not being present yet.
- You will likely also want a resize handler to ensure the iframe gets resized as needed - just be sure to clean it up when the component unmounts.
- You have to be careful of how different browsers report the height. Go for the largest you can find.
- You may have issues if the iframe content is in a different domain than your code. There are solutions out there such as [react-iframe-resizer-super](https://github.com/zeroasterisk/react-iframe-resizer-super) that try to solve this problem in a cross-domain compatible way.

```js
class WrappedFrame extends React.Component {
  state = { contentHeight: 100 };

  handleResize = () => {
    const { body, documentElement } = this.container.contentWindow.document;
    const contentHeight = Math.max(
      body.clientHeight,
      body.offsetHeight,
      body.scrollHeight,
      documentElement.clientHeight,
      documentElement.offsetHeight,
      documentElement.scrollHeight
    );
    if (contentHeight !== this.state.contentHeight) this.setState({ contentHeight });
  };
  
  onLoad = () => {
    this.container.contentWindow.addEventListener('resize', this.handleResize);
    this.handleResize();
  }
  
  componentWillUnmount() {
    this.container.contentWindow.removeEventListener('resize', this.handleResize);
  }
  
  render() {
    const { contentHeight } = this.state;
    return (
      <iframe
        frameBorder="0"
        onLoad={this.onLoad}
        ref={(container) => { this.container = container; }}
        scrolling="no"
        src="your.source"
        style={{ width: '100%', height: `${contentHeight}px` }}
        title="Some Content"
      />
    );
  }
}
```

In this example we're storing the determined content height in the component's state and using that state to set the height of the rendered iframe. Also, by putting the `onLoad()` handler definition in the component, you save a tiny bit of performance in `render()` by not creating a new handler function on every re-render.

Comment: This worked well for me. Notice missing comma in `handleResize` function in the `contentHeight` definition. Can't edit myself — edits has to be 6 characters.

Answer (score 2):

This npm package will do what you what, it offers a range of different ways to calculate the height of the content in the iframe

https://www.npmjs.com/package/iframe-resizer-react

With this use case it can be configured as follows

```
<IframeResizer
    heightCalculationMethod="bodyScroll"
    src="http://anotherdomain.com/iframe.html"
/>
```

Comment: Except IframeResizer "The page in the iframe then needs (iframeResizer.contentWindow.min.js) from iframe-resizer." so that's no good if its not your page loading in the Iframe!

Comment: @James either you have some control over the iFrame, or you probably shouldn't be trying to interfere with it. The script in the iframe is designed to be a good guest on someone else's site, if you need to ask a third party to host it for you.

Answer (score 1):

None of the answers proposed so far worked for me. The hackish approach of doing a short `setTimeout` from within `onLoad` kind-of seems to do the job, at least in my case.

```
class SmartIFrame extends React.Component {
    render() {
        return <iframe srcDoc={this.props.srcDoc}
                       scrolling="no"
                       frameBorder={0}
                       width="100%"
                       onLoad = {e => setTimeout(() => {
                           const obj = ReactDOM.findDOMNode(this);
                           obj.style.height = obj.contentWindow.document.body.scrollHeight + 'px';
                       }, 50)}/>
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Just use useState and useEffect with setTimeout with 100miliseconds and you are done

```
 const [frameHeight , setFrameHeight] = useState()

useEffect(() => {

 const frame = document.getElementById('myFrame');
 console.log("height" , frame.contentWindow.document.body.scrollHeight + "px")
        
 setTimeout(() => {
   setFrameHeight(frame.contentWindow.document.body.scrollHeight + "px")
  },100)


 },[])
       return (
            <iframe srcdoc={content}
            id="myFrame"
            width="100%" 
            height={frameHeight}
            frameBorder="0"
            scrolling="no"
            ></iframe>
     )
```

You'r Welcome !

Answer (score 0):

The best and reliable way to fit iframe is to use

```
iframe-resizer package.

https://www.npmjs.com/package/iframe-resizer
```